# Getting error on opening Microsoft remote desktop: The file “com.microsoft.rdc.application-data.sqlite” couldn’t be opened

Tags: remote-desktop, microsoft

My mac has turned off due to a power cut. Now every time I open Microsoft remote desktop I have the following error **The file “com.microsoft.rdc.application-data.sqlite” couldn’t be opened.**. I tried to uninstall and install RDP but nothing helped. So I need to enter IP, user, password now and again when I open RDP. Does someone have any idea how to fix this issue? [image]

Comment: SQLite database is damaged. Try backing it up, removing the file and restarting RDP App. It should recreate it. You’ll likely need to redo your connections.

Comment: Alternatively, grab the last known good from Time Machine.

Comment: @JamesBrickley Where this file is located? I can't find it

Comment: Or what is the way to remove RDP completely and install it from the scratch?

Comment: Spotlight found it in ~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.rdc.macos/. Move that whole folder somewhere else to back it up. Then retry.

Comment: ~/Library/Containers is where sandboxed Apps store data.

Comment: @JamesBrickley Problem is that there is no such folder/file (com.microsoft.rdc....) under ~/Library/Containers

Comment: There would be if you are running a recent version of Microsoft RDP from AppStore or downloaded from Microsoft. Also a recent macOS version. Newer versions run in an isolated sandbox container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case (on MacOs Big Sur) the folder **com.microsoft.rdc.macos** was located in the `~/Library/Containers/Microsoft Remote Desktop/Data/Library/Application Support` folder. I removed `Microsoft Remote Desktop` folder and the problem solved